# Quarkus 2.6 not load message context

Tags: quarkus

I have the following situation when migrating and compiling in native mode a quarkus service from version 2.5 to 2.6 and it is the following:

We have a JAR which contains the definition of traversal objects used by several services, within these are the validation messages used in the javax.validation.constraints annotations defined in a file called **ValidationMessages.properties**

Until version 2.5 I could include this jar as part of the service dependencies, it performed the native compilation of the service and managed to load these messages through the context without any additional configuration.

Now when migrating to version 2.6 it is not able to locate the default file but always looks for one depending on the region of the system:

The specific message is the following:

````
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name ValidationMessages, locale es_MX
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2055)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1689)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1593)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1284)```
````

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Can you open a GitHub issue please? It will also be extremely helpful to include a sample project

Comment: The solution to this incident was to include the **ValidationMessages.properties** file as part of the resources to be taken into account in the native compilation.